# Capitalizing text of a specific column in R's data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data that looks like this:

```
GO:2000974 7,8 negative_regulation_of_pro-B_cell_differentiation Notch1 ISS
GO:2000974 7,8 negative_regulation_of_pro-B_cell_differentiation Q9W737 IEA
GO:0001768 4 establishment_of_T_cell_polarity Ccl19 IEA 
GO:0001768 4 establishment_of_T_cell_polarity Ccl19 ISS 
GO:0001768 4 establishment_of_T_cell_polarity Ccl21 IEA
```

What I want to do is to capitalize the text of the **fourth** column.
So for example now we have `Notch1`, it'll then be converted to `NOTCH1`.
What's the way to do it in R? I'm stuck with this:

```
dat<-read.table("http://dpaste.com/1353034/plain/")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the `toupper` function:

```
R> toupper(c("a", "ab"))
[1] "A"  "AB"
```

For your data frame, you will have:

```
dat[,4] = toupper(dat[,4])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW I have another data that looks like this http://dpaste.com/1353038/plain/ . Which I wan't to upper case the first column. But why this doesn't work? `dat<-read.table("http://dpaste.com/1353038/plain/");dat[,1]=toupper(dat[,1])`

Comment: the row names was not capitalized in the 2nd dataset.

Comment: If they are row names, then you'll need to use `rownames(dat)`